# Shapefiles not aligning in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, extents

I am trying to align two shapefiles ([LA County freeways](https://egis3.lacounty.gov/dataportal/tag/freeways/) and [LA County city boundaries](https://data.lacounty.gov/GIS-Data/City-Boundaries/wyja-ysz2)) to see which freeways run in each city.

In QGIS, the shapefiles don't align. The freeway layer has a warning question mark saying "no CRS set for layer," however once I set the CRS to match the city boundaries layers (WGS 84 epsg:4326), nothing changes. I "save feature as" shapefile with the same CRS and the imported result is still misaligned with the boundaries.

I tried to export the file again, setting the extent to match the city boundaries, but then it just exports with 0 features.

How can I get the files to align? Specifically, how do I get a file with no CRS to align with another if simply setting the CRS and re-importing does not work?

Comment: Your freeway shields are in NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet (ESRI:102245) which is mentioned in the source https://qgis.org/api/qgscoordinatereferencesystem__legacy_8h_source.html but the boundaries are WGS84 Geographic (EPSG:4326) have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280871/loading-nad83-and-wgs84-layers-together-in-qgis which might help, though I'm no expert in northern hemisphere coordinate systems to assay the efficacy of those posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I downloaded both files and they worked fine for me by simply dragging and dropping the `.shp` components onto the map canvas with the project CRS set to [EPSG:4326](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/).

QGIS loaded the freeways layer in [EPSG:2229 NAD83 / California zone 5](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2229/) so if you need to manually set the CRS, set it to that - not EPSG:4326).

[image: example]

Double check that the `.prj` sidecar file is present in the same location as the rest of the files. If there is no `.prj`-file, you can either download the file again or remove the layer from your project, reload it and then manually set the layer CRS to EPSG:2229.

Comment: Thank you. Setting the CRS to `EPSG:2229 NAD83 / California zone 5` worked. I assumed it was 4326, usually I get a message if it's not.